# How to apply a function with multiple arguments on raster in R?

Tags: r, apply, raster, mapply

I have to apply a function with multiple arguments over a raster stack in R.
My function is:

```
predict_np <- function(fPET_PM, Bc.star, index, model.np){
eval.data <- data.frame(X1 = fPET_PM, X2 = Bc.star)
sim_fPET <- predict(model.np[[index]], newdata = eval.data)
return(sim_fPET)
}
```

I have three arguments (fPET_PM, Bc.star, and index) in above function as raster and fourth argument (i.e. model.np) as a list containing different fitted model (basically, which fitted model will be used for prediction will be based on index value). How the above function can be applied to get a predicted raster output using the arguments as explained above.

I am creating the sample data below:

```
library(raster)
library(np)

fPET_PM <- matrix(runif(400),20,20)
fPET_PM <- raster(fPET_PM)
extent(fPET_PM) <- c(36,37,-3,-2)
projection(fPET_PM) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")

Bc.star <- matrix(runif(400),20,20)
Bc.star <- raster(Bc.star)
extent(Bc.star) <- c(36,37,-3,-2)
projection(Bc.star) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")

index <- matrix(round(runif(400, 1,47)),20,20)
index <- raster(index)
extent(index) <- c(36,37,-3,-2)
projection(index) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
```

Here is the link to the list of fitted models:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TpGZMLQZZd6FhCMMhsBtHw6NDaC5furz/view?usp=sharing

I tried following code so far:

```
out <- predict_np(fPET_PM, Bc.star, index, model.np)
```

But not working!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this

```
s <- stack(fPET_PM, Bc.star, index)
names(s) <- c("fPET_PM", "Bc.star", "index")

out <- predict(s, model.np)
```